# Read highlight words to txt file in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want read highlight color equal yellow words from word to text file.(correct answer questions)
I am know read txt file but I dont read highlights texts.

MY WORD FILE :
[image: word file]

I want read correct answers.

```
OUTPUT : C B C A
```

My code:

```
 object missObj = Missing.Value;
            object path = @"D:\test.doc";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref path, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range in doc.Words)
            {
                if (range.HighlightColorIndex == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(range.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I'm trying

Comment: Linq? Simple scenario: Find all with "__)", push into string collection.

Comment: @TezWingfield  "__)" I do not simply put, for example,

Comment: Hi, My comment was a very naïve/simple approach. I believe you could solve this issue without an answer being given. A little trial and error?

Comment: I dont understood you :(

Comment: So, just print `range.Text` and `range.HighlightColorIndex` to the console to find out the actual value of `HighlightColorIndex` for each range? Or, set a breakpoint and inspect the `range` object for the ranges you are interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you cant find these words becouse it's not highlighted `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow` but just `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdYellow`, also You cant cast `range.ToString` need to use `range.Text` to get text. This sample show how get these words:

```
 public void GetColorText()
    {
        string output = String.Empty;
        object missObj = Missing.Value;
        object path = @"C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\test.docx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref path, ref missObj, ref missObj,
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj,
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range in doc.Words)
        {
            if (range.HighlightColorIndex == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdYellow)
            {
                output += $"{range.Text} ";
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

Comment: This code working it was tested. What exactly not working?

Comment: sorry..this is code error:   test.doc locked editin by  "user" ??

Comment: Its not problem with code, but with permission to your .doc file. The document _file name_ is locked for editing by another user. To open a read-only copy of his document, click...

Comment: When i am click To open a read-only copy of his document Then opening this word(test.doc) but output null

Comment: You have to use 3th option,_send notification when the original will be available_